# Deploy JAR file on WildFly 8.2

Tags: deployment, ejb, wildfly

I want to deploy an EJB Maven project and when I try so, an error message appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjov.png).

The error message :

> 17:45:21,005 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "dashboard-ejb.jar")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"dashboard-ejb.jar#dashboard-ejb\".**FIRST_PHASE** is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.dsOoredoo]"]}

To note, I've created a datasource called `dsOoredoo`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your EJB as well as the contents of your *persistence.xml* file?

Comment: Thank you aribeiro for responding .I resolved the problem in fact in the persistance file "persistance.xml" the name of the datasource was wrong It was an old one I remplaced with the new one that I created and It worked Thank you